# How to sort dataframe columns using for loop

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, dataframe, multiple-columns

I have a Python Dataframe (named dfFull) that outputs the following:

```
Email         System 6 System 7 System 1 System 4 Count System 5 System 3 System 2
test1@test.com  1         0         0        0       2     1         0       0
test2@test.com  0         1         0        1       3     0         1       0
test3@test.com  0         0         1        1       4     1         0       1
```

The amount of systems vary (the amount of systems is calculated earlier in the code and is equal to the variable SystemCount). I would like to restructure the Dataframe to have the email and count column first, than all the systems in order afterwards.

I thought using a for loop would be best for this and have the loop set up below, but I'm not sure what to put inside the loop since I want the email and count column first (Python newbie). I also know that sort_values() would probably work, but even with the python documentation I couldn't get the arguments to work properly

```
for count in range(1, int(SystemCount)+1): #counts up to the system amount
```

Expected out put would be the columns and their contents in this order:

```
Email Count System 1 ..... System 8
```

Comment: What is expected output?

Comment: This has been added, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create [lambda key function](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#key-functions) by all columns from [`difference`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.difference.html) of first columns names:

```
c = ['Email','Count']
c1 = df.columns.difference(c)
cols = c +  sorted(c1, key=lambda x: int(x.split()[1]))
print (cols)
['Email', 'Count', 'System 1', 'System 2', 'System 3', 
 'System 4', 'System 5', 'System 6', 'System 7']

df = df[cols]
print (df)
            Email  Count  System 1  System 2  System 3  System 4  System 5  \
0  test1@test.com      2         0         0         0         0         1   
1  test2@test.com      3         0         0         1         1         0   
2  test3@test.com      4         1         1         0         1         1   

   System 6  System 7  
0         1         0  
1         0         1  
2         0         0
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, can you help me understand this section of the code sorted(c1, key=lambda x: int(x.split()[1]))

Comment: You can create [lambda key function](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#key-functions) for custom formating - here split values of columns by whitespace, seelct second value and convert to `int`, what is used for sorting.